# Fragment should not restart on screen orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

As I am using different layouts for portrait and landscape view. I am using these different layouts in fragment.

To retain the state of fragment, I have added:

```
      setRetainInstance(true);
```

in fragment constrtuctor. Also I have added

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in the activity tag contains fragment.

Now I dont want my fragment to restart again as I am showing progress bar with percentage while downloading a book in this fragment, so when the fragment restarts again, it will again take time to load the page and does not show the progress bar.

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"